# JSONException has been occurred when trying to convert html string to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I know there a lot of people with the same problem but any answers can help me. And all just confuse me.
I'm trying to do a Login/Register on Android.
The problem display is the follow.

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject 
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
...
```

This is my code.

```
final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rButton);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

}

And of course the php one.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");


$name = $_POST["name"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $name, $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
```

Thanks in advance for the help and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: what response you are getting from server end?

Comment: a error ocured in your php code.

Comment: there is a problem in your php script run it in browser and paste its response here.

Comment: Show us the response json.

Comment: Sorry a lot for the delay and thanks for the response Im noobie here

Comment: [http://jocadoci.site88.net/Register.php] there is the php site

Comment: Give me four warnings in my code line: 2, 8, 9 and 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a fellow who help me out I could fix my problem, all begging with the web host that I was using (000webhost) I do not exactly what problem have when you run you php files there, I change my web host to hostiger and I change a little my php code in the second line.

> $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

In the host I leave "localhost" and user, password and database is the one the web host page give you. 
With this and changing my domain in my requests codes my app is running perfectly.
Thanks to everyone who take time to read and answer this post.